# Reschedule Alarms immediately on device reboot Android Oreo

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I want to reschedule my application's alarms immediately after device reboot*. For this process I make a query to my local DB in order to get the alarm details and then set them to the `AlarmManager`. These actions have to be executed in a background thread. 
So I tried the following:

1) I put the above code inside a `JobIntentService` and called `enqueueWork()` but obviously the work was not executed immediately.

2) I put the above code inside a `Service` (in an `AsyncTask`) and called `startForegroundService`. This seems to work but this is not a correct case to use a Foreground Service based on Android documentation.

3) Create a scheduled job and set `setMinimumLatency(0)` in order the code to be executed immediately.

Which do you believe is the most correct way to schedule immediately the alarms? Do you have any other suggestions?

*In the `onReceive()` of the `BroadcastReceiver` for `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` action.

Comment: I believe the safest way to ensure the code will run right after boot would be using a foreground service. If it'll just check the app's db and set the alarms, it'll be really quick and not bother the user.

Answer (score 0):

> As part of the Android 8.0 (API level 26) Background Execution Limits,
>   apps that target the API level 26 or higher can no longer register
>   broadcast receivers for implicit broadcasts in their manifest.

But fortunately `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` **is exempted from above rule.** [Source](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html)

Therefore you can define a `BroadcastReceiver` with `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` action and then in `onReceive` method, delegate the alarm scheduling work to background thread using `JobIntentService` or `ForegroundService`

Comment: This is what I did till now but Android O throws an exception because you are not allowed to start a background service when app is in background or killed. From Google docs: Note: IntentService is subject to all the background execution limits imposed with Android 8.0 (API level 26). In most cases, you are better off using JobIntentService, which uses jobs instead of services when running on Android 8.0 or higher.

Comment: @Fivos I have a similar use case.  What alarm scheduling code on a background thread can be used since JobIntentService has been deprecated?